# Dokku cannot find 'webpack'

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, webpack

I have an issue with pushing an application that uses webpack to dokku.
Webpack itself is located in the `devDependencies` of the `package.json`.

Once pushed it starts installing node_modules. But once it starts to execute the 'postinstall' script it says the following:

```
sh: 1: webpack: not found

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--quiet" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build/.npmrc"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! profortool-app@0.2.0 postinstall: `webpack`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the profortool-app@0.2.0 postinstall script 'webpack'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the profortool-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

Things I tried:

1. Use a bash script to install webpack globally first and then execute webpack.
2. Put webpack in the '`dependencies`' instead of '`devDependencies`'
3. Try to execute webpack locally within the dokku app.

None of these things worked out. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Regards, 
Patrick van Vuuren

Comment: did you try http://webpack.github.io/docs/installation.html ??

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue by placing devDependencies in normal dependencies (probably has something to do with being in production mode on dokku) and I changed the postinstall script to:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Probably dokku has to be configured to development mode to allow dependencies to sit in devDependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Dokku to install the dev dependencies like this:

```
# Enable installing dev dependencies
dokku config: set node - app NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION = false
```